# What is the derivation for the convolution integral for Laplace transforms?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Why is the convolution integral what it is? Everywhere I look, there are proofs showing why the Laplace transform of the convolution is the product of the Laplace transforms, but nowhere does it say how mathematicians happened upon this formula.

Answer (score 0):

See [Convolution theorem](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/laplacetransform/LaplaceConvolutionTheorem.1.pdf) in [COMPLEX ANALYSIS: for Mathematics and Engineering](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/books/cbook.htm).